# How can I pass a serializedObject from Editor script to Editor Window script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    public ConversationsEditorWindow initser()
    {
        ConversationsEditorWindow myWindow = CreateInstance<ConversationsEditorWindow>();
        //myWindow.Init(serializedObject);
        SerializedObject serobject = new SerializedObject(myWindow);
        myWindow.Init(serobject);

        return myWindow;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Configure Item"))
        {
            ConversationsEditorWindow myWindow = CreateInstance<ConversationsEditorWindow>();
            //myWindow.Init(serializedObject);
            myWindow.Init(serializedObject);
        }
    }
}
```

First time I used a button in the OnInspectorGUI and it was working fine with the button. But now I don't want a button in the Editor script but using a item menu in the Editor Window script.

So I created in the Editor script a method called it initser.

Then in the Editor Window :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    public static SerializedObject conversation = null;

    private static ConversationTrigger _conversationTrigger;

    [SerializeField] private static ReorderableList conversationsList;

    private static SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private static int _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;
    private static int newSize = 0;
    private static Vector2 scrollPos;

    private readonly static Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly static Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();

    private static SerializedObject itemcopy;

    [MenuItem("Dialog System/Conversations")]
    private static void ConversationsWindow()
    {
        const int width = 800;
        const int height = 800;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        var window = GetWindow<ConversationsEditorWindow>();
        window.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

        ConversationTriggerEditor triggereditor = new ConversationTriggerEditor();
        triggereditor.initser();
    }


    public void Init(SerializedObject _item)
    {
        // Copy the Item targetObject to not lose reference when you
        // click another element on the project window.
        itemcopy = new SerializedObject(_item.targetObject);
        conversation = itemcopy;

        // Other things to initialize the window
        _conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)_item.targetObject;
        _conversations = itemcopy.FindProperty("conversations");

        conversationsList = new ReorderableList(itemcopy, _conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            drawHeaderCallback = DrawConversationsHeader,

            drawElementCallback = DrawConversationsElement,

            onAddCallback = (list) =>
            {
                SerializedProperty addedElement;
                // if something is selected add after that element otherwise on the end
                if (_currentlySelectedConversationIndex >= 0)
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);
                }

                var name = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var foldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                var dialogues = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                name.stringValue = "";
                foldout.boolValue = false;
                dialogues.arraySize = 0;
            },

            elementHeightCallback = (index) =>
            {
                return GetConversationHeight(_conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));
            }
        };
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (itemcopy != null)
        {
            itemcopy.Update();

            // if there are no elements reset _currentlySelectedConversationIndex
            if (conversationsList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1 < _currentlySelectedConversationIndex) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;
```

Now conversationsList is null.

Before that when I used a button in the Editor script I used here without the menu item without making it static just :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    public static SerializedObject conversation = null;

    private static ConversationTrigger _conversationTrigger;

    [SerializeField] private static ReorderableList conversationsList;

    private static SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private static int _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;
    private static int newSize = 0;
    private static Vector2 scrollPos;

    private readonly static Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly static Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();

    private static SerializedObject itemcopy;




    public void Init(SerializedObject _item)
    {
        // Copy the Item targetObject to not lose reference when you
        // click another element on the project window.
        itemcopy = new SerializedObject(_item.targetObject);
        conversation = itemcopy;

        // Other things to initialize the window
        const int width = 800;
        const int height = 800;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        var window = GetWindow<ConversationsEditorWindow>();
        window.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

        _conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)_item.targetObject;
        _conversations = itemcopy.FindProperty("conversations");

        conversationsList = new ReorderableList(itemcopy, _conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            drawHeaderCallback = DrawConversationsHeader,

            drawElementCallback = DrawConversationsElement,

            onAddCallback = (list) =>
            {
                SerializedProperty addedElement;
                // if something is selected add after that element otherwise on the end
                if (_currentlySelectedConversationIndex >= 0)
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);
                }

                var name = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var foldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                var dialogues = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                name.stringValue = "";
                foldout.boolValue = false;
                dialogues.arraySize = 0;
            },

            elementHeightCallback = (index) =>
            {
                return GetConversationHeight(_conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));
            }
        };
    }
```

In the end what I want to do is to pass the serializedObject from the Editor script to the Editor Window script without a button in the Editor script.

Comment: So what's the role does the Editor script play now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to create a `SerializedObject` of the `EditorWindow` instance as you do in `serobject = new SerializedObject(myWindow);` but rather pass in the `serializedObject` reference of the Editor script.

**The main problem**: You can't simply use

```
ConversationTriggerEditor triggereditor = new ConversationTriggerEditor();
```

This makes no sense. The `ConversationTriggerEditor` instance is created by Unity internally once the according `ConversationTrigger` instance gains focus and the Inspector is loaded. If you create an instance using `new` how should this `ConversationTriggerEditor` instance know which actual `ConversationTrigger` component it belongs to?

---

Instead you have to somhow get a reference of the according `ConversationTrigger` instance e.g. using

```
var conversationTrigger = FindObjectOfType<ConversationTrigger>();
```

and then create the `SerializedObject` from it using

```
var conversationTriggerSerializedObject = new SerializedObject(conversationTrigger);
```

Note that it is very important that you also wrap any changes to the `conversationTriggerSerializedObject` within

```
conversationTriggerSerializedObject.Update();

// ...

conversationTriggerSerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

Comment: Great, Thank you.